# MySQL Replication lag in slave due to Delete query - Row Based Replication

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb, replication

I have a delete query, which delete rows by chunk (each chunk 2000)

```
Delete from Table1 where last_refresh_time < {time value}
```

Here I want to delete the rows in the table which are not refreshed for last 5days.
Usually the delete will be around 10million rows. This process will be done once per-day in a little offtime.

This query executes little faster in Master, but due to **ROW_BASED_REPLICATION** the SLAVE is in heavy lag. As **SLAVE** - **SQL_THREAD** deletes each rows one by one from **RELAY_LOG** data.

We use **READ_COMMITED** isolation level,
Is it okay to change this query transaction alone to STATEMENT_BASED replication ?

will we face any issue?

In MySql, it is mentioned like below, can someone explain this will other transaction INSERT gets affected?

> If you are using InnoDB tables and the transaction isolation level is READ COMMITTED or READ UNCOMMITTED, only row-based logging can be used. It is possible to change the logging format to STATEMENT, but doing so at runtime leads very rapidly to errors because InnoDB can no longer perform inserts

If other **TRANSACTION INSERTS** gets affected can we change **ISOLATION LEVEL** to **REPEATABLE_READ** for this **DELETE QUERY TRANSACTION** alone ? Is it recommended do like this?

Please share your views and Suggestions for this lag issue

Mysql - INNDOB Engine - 5.7.18

Answer (score 4):

Don't do a single `DELETE` that removes 10M rows.  Or 1M.  Not even 100K.

Do the delete online.  Yes, it is possible, and usually preferable.

Write a script that walks through the table 200 rows at a time.  `DELETE` *and `COMMIT`* any "old" rows in that 200.  Sleep for 1 second, then move on to the next 200.  When it hits the end of the table, simply start over.  (1K rows in a chunk may be OK.)  Walk through the table via the `PRIMARY KEY` so that the effort to 'chunk' is minimized.  Note that the 200 rows plus 1 second delay will let you get through the table in about 1 day, effectively as fast as your current code, but will much less interference.

More details:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig  Note, especially, how it is careful to touch *only* N rows (N=200 or whatever) of the table per pass.

My suggestion helps avoid Replica lag in these ways

- Lower count (200 vs 2000).  That many 'events' will be dumped into the replication stream all at once.  Hence, other events are stuck behind them.
- Touch only 200 rows -- by using the `PRIMARY KEY` careful use of `LIMIT`, etc
- "Sleep" between chunks -- The Primary primes the cache with an initial `SELECT` that is not replicated.  Hence, in Row Based Replication, the Replica is likely to be caught off guard (rows to delete have not been cached).  The Sleep gives it a chance to finish the deletes *and handle other replication items* before the next chunk comes.

Discussion:  With Row Based Replication (which is preferable), a 10M `DELETE` will ship 10M 1-row deletes to the Replicas.  This clogs replication, delays replication, etc.  By breaking it into small chunks, such overhead has a reasonable impact on replication.

Don't worry about isolation mode, etc, simply commit each small chunk.  100 rows will easily be done in less than a second.  Probably 1K will be that fast.  10M will certainly not.

You said "refreshed".  Does this mean that the processing updates a timestamp in the table?  And this happens at 'random' times for 'random' rows?  And such an update can happen multiple times for a given row?  If that is what you mean, then I do not recommend `PARTITIONing`, which is also discussed in the link above.

Note that I do not depend on an index on that timestamp, much less suggest partitioning by that timestamp.  I want to avoid the overhead of updating such an index so rapidly.  Walking through the table via the PK is a very good alternative.

Comment: We actually delete rows by chunk (each chunk 2000), but without a sleep. For 10Million rows we thought sleep of 1 sec for each chunk will take extra time to process things.   And for "Refreshed" part, yes the time value will be updated to latest current time whenever the row data changes, so partitioning can't be used here, but updating time is not frequent.  
Btw What's your thought on statement based and repeatable read isolation for this process alone?   Thanks

Comment: 1 sec x 5000 (nb chunk) = 1h 20 of waiting  time... yes you will have minimum of lock and no slave lag (master will work so slow), but it could be very long and use more resources. So it depends of your constraints.

Comment: @vinieth - "statement based and repeatable read" -- I would rather avoid messing with the well-thought-out defaults for these.  Instead work around the issues by, for example, lowering the 2000 and/or adding a sleep -- _if needed_.

Comment: @Mr_Thorynque - I assume that the elapsed time for the purging is not critical; instead, the interference is critical.  Currently, the OP lets items live up to one extra day before purging.  In my scheme, taking 24 hours to make one pass over the table is "just as good" as that 1 day grace period.  My "sleep 1" helps with slave lag and other issues.  (Increasing the 'sleep' too much would take it beyond 1 day to make a pass.)  A chunk size of 200, plus a sleep of 1 second would take about 1 day to check 10M rows.

Comment: @vinieth - I added some more rationale.

Answer (score 2):

Do you really need READ_COMMITED isolation level ? It's not actually standard and ACID.

But any way.
For this query you can change session isolation to REAPEATABLE_READ and use MIXED mode for binlog_format.
With that you will get STATEMENT base replication only for this session.

Maybe that table usage will better fit to noSQL tool like Mongodb and [TTL index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-ttl/).

Comment: To avoid GAP locks and for few other reasons we use READ_COMMITED. And  TTL  can't be used for this, time value in that column will be updated whenever the rows data refreshes.

Other than this will it cause any issue, when different transactions use different  isolation levels ?

Comment: The delete query will involve GAP lock on 1M rows...

Comment: I think with that solution it will use 50% less IO write. And that delete of 10M rows is probably IO bound.